# Search ZIP code range and pull corresponding Zone

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a workbook that has the first three digits of a ZIP code in both columns A and B. A is the lower bound of the range and B is the upper bound. I then have the corresponding zone for that ZIP code range in column C. I tried the following formula with no luck.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((I11>=A10:A101)*(I11<=B10:B101)),D10:D101)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to use this formula to grab the appropriate zone for any ZIP code entered, to streamline the process of doing a cost analysis for a potential customer. If it is easier to achieve this using a VBA script I am open to that as well.

Here is an example of the first three rows of data from my workbook:

```
Lower Bounds | Upper Bounds | Zone
004          | 005          | 008
006          | 007          | 045
009          |              | 045
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Lower Bounds` is in A1 and what you are looking up in E2, please try:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,A:A))
```

Make sure ColumnA is sorted ascending.

Comment: I tried using the full zip and just the first 3 digits but its still outputting #N/A. I put the value I am searching for in E2 and the formula in F2. Oh and I made sure the list is sorted as ascending.

Comment: If i pull one of the values from Column A into E2 it works, but the value wont always be exactly as in Column A since each zone has a range of zip codes. It uses the first 3 digits of the zip codes.

Comment: Whoops guess I did have an extra space in there. This is working great now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Is removing the upper bounds and creating a two column list out of the question?
If not then you can use =LOOKUP(2,A10:A101,C10:D101)

```
Zip  Zone
004  008
005  008
006  045
007  045
009  045
```

Comment: I tried removing the upper bounds and making the list just 2 columns. The data is now from A10:C101, so I used the following formula. `=LOOKUP(2,A10:A101,B10:B101)`